# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre atributo class y atributo id?

Tags: html

¿Cuál sería la diferencia entre el atributo `class` y el atributo `id`?

¿Tienen algún uso especifico cada uno de los mismos?

Comment: `class`=> clase del elemento `id`=> identificador del elemento, el identificador es único y la clase puede ser común, es la mayor diferencia

Comment: ¿Has investigado algo? Tu pregunta es perfectamente respondida [en la documentación](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/review-drafts/2020-01/). En cuanto a la cuestión de los estilos y demás, son conceptos básicos de CSS. Dado que los estilos se aplican en cascada, es necesario tener clara la prioridad de los elementos, por ejemplo, el `id` sirve para aplicar estilos, y tendría prioridad sobre la clase. Es importante saberlo para no aplicar estilos de forma que se **rompa** la cascada, quedando un código mal optimizado.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por tu respuesta, respecto a la documentación, no sabía de su existencia, estoy empezando ahora en esto de la programación, supongo que disculpa por hacer ese tipo de preguntas. - a partir de ahora le echaré antes un vistazo siempre a la documentación :)

Comment: No hay problema, en programación todo tiene su documentación (te aconsejo siempre revisar los sitios oficiales de cada lenguaje/tecnología/API..., aunque generalmente están en inglés). Lo digo porque mucha gente usa sitios como w3schools porque son de los primeros que aparecen en Google, pero usan ejemplos y prácticas obsoletos muchas veces y otras veces usan código que induce a malas prácticas de programación.

Comment: @A.Cedano De hecho hace 1 hora estuve echándole un vistazo a esa pagina web, pero después de lo que has dicho, me pondré a buscar las paginas web oficiales en vez de usar w3schools, Muchas gracias de nuevo por el consejo, seguro que me ayudará mucho a hacer las cosas bien desde el principio!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

el atributo class te ayuda a enlazar un estilo de CSS (lo que define el aspecto de ese elemento, y todos los demás elementos donde apliques ese CSS). Por ejemplo:

```
.rojo { background-color: red; }
<div class="rojo">Hola</div>
<div class="rojo">Qué tal</div>
```

Y el atributo id te permite identificar ese elemento de forma única en todo el documento para usarlo después, ya bien sea con CSS o con javascript.

```
.rojo { background-color: red; }
<div class="rojo">Hola</div>
<div id="rojo" class="rojo">Qué tal</div>
document.getElementById('rojo').innerHTML = 'Qué tal, bien gracias.'
```

Los "id" no deben repetirse en mismo documento o ocurrirán comportamientos inesperados.

Resumiendo, con un id actúas directamente en el elemento que quieres y con class puedes actuar masivamente en todos los elementos que usen esa clase.

Comment: Bastante útil, respondió mi duda, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

De manera literal o con una analogía te lo explico:

```
class="Son tus caracteríticas como persona, medio económicos, etc"

id="Es tu identidad, de esa manera te pueden identificar a traves de tu Cedula/NIT donde quieras que lo soliciten"
```

Muchas personas pueden pertenecer a la misma clase y tener condiciones parecidas, pero nadie puede tener el mismo `id=""` y en caso de dos personas tener el mismo `id=""` las dos tendrian problemas con la ley si una de ellas está en el momento y lugar equivocado.

Así mismo funciona en html, supongamos que quiero una misma `class=""` para todos mis formularios, entonces en CSS yo defino que la `class="mis formularios"` tengan todos las letras azules, ahora bien, necesito que el formulario 1 esté en un sitio y el 2 en otro sitio, es ahí donde viene el `id=""` debo identificar cada elemento de cada formulario con nombres distintos porque a pesar de que tienen la misma `class=""` son dos elementos independientes y no quiero que lo que haga con uno afecte al otro como por ejemplo a la hora de guardar los datos en una base de datos.